# router can not distinguish local ip address and vpn ipadress

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, local

I recently bought an Asus RT-N66U router.
when I run VPN against a network it goes fine to connect but I can not run RDP against servers on that network because the servers are in the range 192.168.1 ....., and my local ip address is 192.168.1.5
it seems that the router can not distinguish between local network and VPN network
when i try to ping the server on the VPN-network i get general failure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have an IP addressing/routing conflict. For IP routing to work correctly, a given address (or subnet / range of addresses) can only appear in one location in the larger internetwork. Since both your remote VPN server's network and your local home LAN use the same subnet, you've got problems; your own VPN client device doesn't know if packets to the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet should be delivered directly to the local LAN or sent through the VPN tunnel to the remote VPN server. So connectivity to some 192.168.1.x hosts is broken.

Most people in your situation don't have control over the configuration of the VPN server they're connecting to, so it's usually easiest to reconfigure your home LAN to use a different subnet.

You might want to contact your VPN provider to find out a complete list of RFC 1918 private subnets that they use on their network, so that you can avoid using any of them on your home LAN. In some cases, the list of subnets that are being routed over the VPN link is something you can look up in your VPN client UI or in its configuration files, or by inspecting your OS's routing table when the VPN connection is up. But if you can't determine it yourself one of those ways, or if it's configured as a "full tunnel" VPN where *all* traffic gets routed through the VPN, then you'll have to ask your VPN administrator.

Edited to add: What VPN server admin uses the 192.168.1.x/24 subnet for setting up a VPN server? That's such a common home network subnet it's guaranteed to cause problems for many users. No professional VPN service or corporate IT pro would set it up this way. Whoever set this up must be pretty inexperienced with setting up VPN servers, because this is a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think its easy to change the IP of your router to avoid this routing conflict. Just access the admin panel of your [Asus RT-N66U router](https://routerify.com/asus/rt-n66u/) and change your IP to some other subnet, so that you will not face such kind of conflict.